# Run Geoserver platform independent binary over https?

Tags: java, jetty, geoserver

I am new to work on Geoserver,now i have a requirement to run geoserver over https. I had followed some steps to configure jetty for https but it didn't work,i might have went wrong somewhere.

[image]

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No constructor class org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector([],{}) in file:/C:/Users/sanja/Downloads/geoserver-2.17.1-bin/etc/jetty-https.xml
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:406)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1558)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1512)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1511)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:220)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:490)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:77)
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:220)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:490)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No constructor class org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector([],{}) in file:/C:/Users/sanja/Downloads/geoserver-2.17.1-bin/etc/jetty-https.xml
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:406)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1558)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1512)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1511)
        ... 7 more
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:220)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:490)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No constructor class org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector([],{}) in file:/C:/Users/sanja/Downloads/geoserver-2.17.1-bin/etc/jetty-https.xml
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:406)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1558)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1512)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1511)
        ... 7 more
```

These are the errors(ref image).

I am not so good in java too.

Comment: Please add the commentary for the errors as text, not image. It will be easier for those with assistive needs to be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Don't run the platform independent binary in production!**

If you still need to add HTTPS support then you need to follow the [Eclipse instructions to add HTTPS to Jetty](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-ssl.html).

Without knowing how far you got along that path it's impossible to give any further advice.

Comment: YES....finally its working now over https,but still shows "Not Secure",thats probably due to self-signed certificate. Thank you @Ian Turton Sir.

Comment: please accept the answer if it solved your problem - or add your own answer describing the exact steps you took to set up HTTPS. While you're at it please take the [tour] to see how this site works to help you in future

Comment: @IanTurton why is it not recommended to run geoserver as a platform independent binary in production ?

Comment: Why is it bad to run the PID in production? @IanTurton

Comment: because it is a small unoptimized jetty server which is not configured for production usage.