# Geoserver in production

Tags: ubuntu, geoserver

Why is it not recommended to run geoserver as a platform independent binary in production ? as said by [Ian Turton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62600835/run-geoserver-platform-independent-binary-over-https/67180654#67180654)